# Maven gives dependencies issues

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am using Eclipse 2020-06 (4.16.0) version.
In my application I have maven-compiler-plugin defined in my Pom.xml like below.
I also have the specific jars in /users/.m2/repository folder.
When I run the Maven on my project, I still get this error.
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project <>: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
Also I see the below error:
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\XXXXXXX.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.6\httpclient-4.5.6.jar; ZipFile invalid LOC header (bad signature)

I thought httpclient jar file and maven-compiler-plugin got corrupted. I downloaded from internet and did mvn install. Still I see these errors. How can we resolve it.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: First turn on checkSumPolicy https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/ Have you tried to run your build on plain command line? If so you should clean your local cache; turn on checksum policy..and rebuilt your project...

Comment: @Khmarbaise, Yes I tried to ran on plain command line. Still the same error.

Comment: Ok..now we have excluded Eclipse as cause(which. I didn't expect but to be sure)... now follow the suggestions of @David M Karr...

Answer (score 1):

In your .m2/repository tree, remove the entire "4.5.6" directory.  In your project directory, rerun "mvn -U" package (-U is probably overkill after deleting the directory, but it's a good habit to get into, to ensure that dependencies are redownloaded).  Verify that it shows Maven redownloading the httpclient artifact.  If you still see the same error, look at the contents of the downloaded "httpclient-4.5.6.jar" file.  In this case, I expect it will be a text file, containing html output.  If so, that means there is something wrong with your proxy settings in your settings.xml file.